# Существительные вместе или раздельно с частицей "не"?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

1. В случае **не достижения** согласия.
2. **Не вертикальность** стен.
3. В случае **не уведомления**.

Я думала, что вместе, если можно заменить на синоним, а WORD подчеркивает как ошибку, если вместе. Подскажите, как правильно. Заранее благодарю, Екатерина.

Comment: @Екатерина1949, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

WORD неправ. Вы -- правы.

Правильно -- слитно: *недостижение, невертикальность, неуведомление.*

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, Word анализирует не дальше пары "слов" - на то он и Word, а не искусственный интеллект. Простое отрицание встречается чаще, и ему это "понятнее".

Это не достижение - так может каждый.

Это не вертикальность, а косой уклон.

Это не уведомление, а вялое напоминание.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж писать такие слова (особенно *невертикальность*), то в вашем случае надо писать слитно. Потому что отрицания нет.

Но вот против *невертикальности* я очень возражаю. Ведь нет такого слова в языке! Не к любому же существительному можно присобачить это НЕ! Я бы написал, например, *отсутствие вертикальности*.

Comment: Niemand: "Но вот против невертикальности я очень возражаю. Ведь нет такого слова в языке!"=== Это оттого, что Вы не работаете в отраслях, где этот термин используется. Посмотрите, к примеру, ГОСТ 21780-2006 "СИСТЕМА ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЯ ТОЧНОСТИ
ГЕОМЕТРИЧЕСКИХ ПАРАМЕТРОВ В СТРОИТЕЛЬСТВЕ": http://www.vashdom.ru/gost/21780-2006/

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, же слитно! А что касается WORD - на него никак нельзя полагаться. Есть свод правил, который надо усвоить.

Answer (score 0):

А вот ГОСТ 21780-2006 - это совсем не свод правил с точки зрения языка.
"Невертикальность" - это ещё что!
В одном ОСТе мне встретилость слово "трудносгораемый" (смысл по контексту - "трудносгорающий"). Так и хочется спросить: "Кто его сгорал?.."

Comment: СГОРАЕМЫЙ - способный гореть, сгорать, горючий. Сгораемые материалы. Несгораемые материалы. Это прилагательное, а не причастие. Только причастия должны образовываться от переходных глаголов (сгорать что?).

Comment: Это прилагательное, потому что мы его так назвали. Это исключение, потому что мы его сделали таковым. Но оно в принципе ничем не отличается от *спимых* детей и *умираемых* со смеху людей.

Comment: Глагольную форму со значением признака как действие мы назвали причастием. Глагольную форму со значением постоянного признака мы назвали прилагательным. Сгорающий - тот, которого в данный момент сгорает (причастие). Видимый мной - тот, которого я вижу в данный момент (причастие, образованное от переходного глагола, при наличии производителя действия). (Большинство форм на МЫЙ являются прилагательными). Сгораемый - тот, который имеет способность гореть (прилагательное, образованное от непереходного глагола).